# Sql count number of tested models by car brands

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables the first one is tests which contains tested brand_id and model_id and brands which
contains car brands and lastly models which contains brand_id.
I want to show all brands and models and number of tests for respective model. If no tests than it should be zero.
This is what I achieved so far;

```
select
    b.id,
    b.brand_name,
    m.model_name,
    (select sum(coalesce(count(m.id), 0)) from test where test.brand_id = b.id and test.model_id = m.id) model_count
from
    brands b
left join models m on
    m.brand_id = b.id
left join test t on
    t.brand_id = b.id
group by
    b.brand_name,
    m.model_name
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group by as follows:

```
select
    b.id,
    b.brand_name,
    m.model_name,
    count(t.brand_id) model_count
from brands b join models m on m.brand_id = b.id
left join test t on t.brand_id = b.id and t.model_id = m.id
group by b.id, b.brand_name, m.model_name
```

Answer (score 1):

A correlated subquery is a perfectly reasonable way to solve this problem.  But . . . you don't don't `test` in the outer query and the subquery can be much simplified:

```
select b.id, b.brand_name,  m.model_name,
      (select count(*)
       from test t
       where t.brand_id = b.id and t.model_id = m.id
      ) as model_count
from brands b left join
     models m
     on m.brand_id = b.id;
```

Under many circumstances, this will have *better* performance than the equivalent aggregation query because it avoids aggregation over the entire data set.